# Bottom Gradient Border

Tags: gradient, css

According to [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/), the following CSS syntax would result in left border gradient.

```
.left-to-right {
border-width:3px 0 3px 3px;
-webkit-border-image: 
    -webkit-gradient(linear, 100% 0, 0 0, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
-webkit-border-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(right, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-o-border-image:
         -o-linear-gradient(right, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
-moz-border-image:
       -moz-linear-gradient(right, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;   
}
```

I'm trying to get the border gradient on the bottom of the element.

I tried changing this

```
    border-width:3px 0 3px 3px;
```

to this

```
border-width:0 0 3px 0;
```

this

```
border-width:0 3px 3px 3px;
```

And it doesn't work, can anybody help me with getting that bottom border to work?

*You may need a WebKit browser to do this.*

Here would be a fiddle for one to work with; http://jsfiddle.net/HsTcf/

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
border-width: 0 0 3px 0;
```

is correct.

However, the following changed needed to be made:

```
... -gradient(right, ...
```

needed to be changed to

```
... -gradient(top, ...
```

and `1 100%;` to `100% 1;`.

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/HsTcf/3](http://jsfiddle.net/HsTcf/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that works for bottom borders. This is the complete class declaration from a site example.

```css
#header_bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 121px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_bg"></div>
```

I am assuming above you are trying to make a fixed header. The most important part of course is the box-shadow property. This will work in most modern browsers as well.