# Border Image with Linear Gradient

Tags: jquery, css, border, linear-gradients

I not expert in Jquery, but I tried build **underline color** with **random color** for `each li` like example this is a rough structure : [Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bnhjw6ap/3/)

I use function random color in Jquery, how to set `Linear gradient` in `function random color` to looks like example ?

I try

```
FROM
return 'radial-gradient(at top left, '+c1.rgb+'25%,'+c2.rgb+'50%,'+c3.rgb+'100%)';

TO
return 'linear-gradient(left, '+c1.rgb+'25%,'+c2.rgb+'50%,'+c3.rgb+'100%) 0 0 100% 0/0 0 5px 0 stretch';
```

And change function Jquery from `background` to `border`, but not working

Could you please tell me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a css property called [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border), it takes as a param the thickness, the type of border and the color of the border

if you want to use a gradient use the css property [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)

```
<div class="box">

  hey there
</div>
```

css:

```
.box{
      width: 250px;
      height: 20px;
      background: transparent;
      border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
      -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 24%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 24%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      border-image: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 24%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
      border-image-slice: 1;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/agkety8w/

in your case do the following:
the gradient:

```
 return 'linear-gradient(to left,  '+c1.rgb+' 0%, '+c2.rgb+' 50%, '+c1.rgb+'
```

the function:

```
function PPAP() {
    elements = $('li');
    elements.each(function() { $(this).css({"borderImage":random(), "borderImageSlice": "1","borderBottom": "5px solid transparent"}); });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdeqvoaa/

Comment: do you mean like this `elements.each(function() { $(this).css("border",random()); });` ?

Comment: you will need the border-image property for a gradient

Comment: wow, i still tried build the code, and you already answer , thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 return 'radial-gradient(at bottom, '+c1.rgb+'25%,'+c2.rgb+'50%,'+c3.rgb+'100%)';
```

Here may help you :

[Bottom Gradient Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878649/bottom-gradient-border)